# Django-CKeditor: How to show RichTextFields in templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

The problem is that I want to show the content of a Post in the template but I don't know how

The model of Post is:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post(models.Model):

    ...
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name='contenido')
    ...
```

And in the template I have a for to show all the post that is like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    ...
    {{ post.content }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

But when I see the page in the browser shows this:
< p > Post content < /p >

Instead of this:
Post content

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to mark the content as safe. So change your template to:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    ...
    {{ post.content|safe }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

By default HTML is not escaped and so is displayed as text, which is why you're seeing the `<p>` tags. You need to mark the field as `safe` so that Django renders it as HTML. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I see the answer in other post after I post this question.

Comment: hey buddy, do you know how to style the text in the template? I try `<p class="bootstrap classes"> {{ item.description|safe }} </p>`, but the `bootstrap classes` are not being loaded. how can I style it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
{{article.body|safe}}
```

or

```
{{article.body|truncatechars:150|safe}}
```

or

```
{{article.body|truncatewords:25|safe}}
```